# Newton's method for $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}x^2-y^2+1\\ 2xy\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}0\\0\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$?

Tags: newton-raphson

How do I find first four steps of Newton's method if $f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}x^2-y^2+1\\ 2xy\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $(x_0,y_0)=(1,1)$
?

Let $x^2-y^2+1$ be g(x)
$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=2x$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=-2y$.

$h(x)=2xy$, so $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}=2y$ and $\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}=2x$.

Is the rate of convergence to the solution in accordance with the theory?

Comment: Did you already derive an expression for the Jacobian?

Comment: Do you understand the exercise? What does the identity $$f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}x^2-y^2+1\\ 2xy\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$ even *mean*?

Comment: Not the best @Did

Comment: Since the functions are conjugate harmonics, can't we write the system in complex variables as $z^2+1=0$ and solve that?

Comment: @Oscar, well sure, but I think you're spoiling the point of the exercise... ;) June, again: since you have the partial derivatives, can you now construct the Jacobian, and then its inverse?

Comment: OK.  Still has a bearing on what the Jacobian should look like.

Comment: "Is the rate of convergence to the solution in accordance with the theory?" – I hope so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left\{ \begin{align}
  & {{f}_{1}}(x,y)={{x}^{2}}-{{y}^{2}}+1 \\ 
 & {{f}_{2}}(x,y)=2xy \\ 
\end{align} \right.$$
we have
$$J=\left| \begin{matrix}
   \frac{\partial {{f}_{1}}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial {{f}_{1}}}{\partial y}  \\
   \frac{\partial {{f}_{2}}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial {{f}_{2}}}{\partial y}  \\
\end{matrix} \right|=\left| \begin{matrix}
   2x & -2y  \\
   2y & 2x  \\
\end{matrix} \right|=4{{x}^{2}}+4{{y}^{2}}\ne 0 , \quad (x,y)\in R^2-{(0,0)}$$
and
\begin{align}
  & {{g}_{1}}(x,y)=x-\frac{\left| \begin{matrix}
   {{f}_{1}} & \frac{\partial {{f}_{1}}}{\partial y}  \\
   {{f}_{2}} & \frac{\partial {{f}_{2}}}{\partial y}  \\
\end{matrix} \right|}{\left| \begin{matrix}
   \frac{\partial {{f}_{1}}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial {{f}_{1}}}{\partial y}  \\
   \frac{\partial {{f}_{2}}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial {{f}_{2}}}{\partial y}  \\
\end{matrix} \right|}=x-\frac{2{{x}^{3}}+2x{{y}^{2}}+2x}{4{{x}^{2}}+4{{y}^{2}}} \\ 
 & {{g}_{2}}(x,y)=y-\frac{\left| \begin{matrix}
   \frac{\partial {{f}_{1}}}{\partial x} & {{f}_{1}}  \\
   \frac{\partial {{f}_{2}}}{\partial x} & {{f}_{2}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right|}{\left| \begin{matrix}
   \frac{\partial {{f}_{1}}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial {{f}_{1}}}{\partial y}  \\
   \frac{\partial {{f}_{2}}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial {{f}_{2}}}{\partial y}  \\
\end{matrix} \right|}=y-\frac{2{{y}^{3}+2{{x}^{2}}y}-2y}{4{{x}^{2}}+4{{y}^{2}}} \\ 
\end{align}
as result
\begin{align}
  & {{x}_{k+1}}={{g}_{1}}({{x}_{k}},{{y}_{k}})={{x}_{k}}-\frac{2{{x}_{k}}^{3}+2{{x}_{k}}{{y}_{k}}^{2}+2{{x}_{k}}}{4{{x}_{k}}^{2}+4{{y}_{k}}^{2}} \\ 
 & {{y}_{k+1}}={{g}_{2}}({{x}_{k}},{{y}_{k}})={{y}_{k}}-\frac{2y_{k}^{3}+2x_{k}^{2}{{y}_{k}}-2{{y}_{k}}}{4{{x}_{k}}^{2}+4{{y}_{k}}^{2}} \\ 
\end{align}

now let $k=0,1,2,3$ and set $(x_0,y_0)=(1,1)$

Comment: In case it wasn't immediately apparent: Behrouz calculated the Jacobian *determinant* and proceeded to use Cramer's rule.