# Newton method and convergence

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

$f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}x^2-y^2+1\\ 2xy\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $(x_0,y_0)=(1,1)$

1. Do the first 4 steps of Newton method. I did this.
2. Show that are many reasonably starting points for the Newton method
   that does not converge. Show that for starting points (x0, 0) on the x-axis
   the metod does not converge.

Can someone help me with 2.?

Comment: This was asked yesterday.. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1830684/newtons-method-for-bigl-beginsmallmatrixx2-y21-2xy-endsmallmatrix-b).